# How can I tag my meditation app under two categories like my competitors on Android Playstore?

Tags: android

We are a meditation app called Idanim, We have tagged ourselves under Health and Fitness categories and that tag is reflecting on our playstore but our competitors are able to tag themselves in two categories. We also want to reflect in health and fitness as well as meditation I am attaching screenshots for reference please help us resolve this.  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tgvh.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b09gg.jpg)

I have tried to explore every way on the backend but I am unable to do it.

Comment: How did you add "Health and Fitness"? Does this help? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859673

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is on Play Console:

- Go to Store presence > Store settings;
- Click on **Manage Tags** button;
- Select desired tags;

Then you should be able to have all of them. (Tried on mine)

[image]

Comment: I get your point but will it reflect on the play store?

Comment: I didn't submit it to Playstore, but it should reflect on App Page.